# How to index and match using R (Match 2 dimensions)

Tags: r, multi-index

I have made good progress on my script but am unable to replicate the 2 dimensional index and match function from Excel in R. I've included a basic example scenario below.

I have two dataframes,

df1 - Column 1 "SKU", Column 2-10 "Country"
column 1 currently has thousands of lines, but column 2-10 are blank.

E.g

```
SKU US  MX  ....
111
123
```

df2 - Column 1 "SKU", Column 2 "Country", Column 3 "Revenue"

```
SKU COUNTRY REVENUE
111 US       $1000
111 MX       $800
123 US       $500
123 MX       $600
```

I'd like to bring in the revenue from df2, into df1 in columns 2-10, to get the following output.

```
SKU US     MX    
111 1000   800
123 500     600
```

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like d1 is your template but doesn't have data, while df2 has all the data but in "long" format. Sounds like you should reshape df2 wide (e.g. with `tidyr::pivot_wider`) and then reorder the columns, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you Jon! Did some research into that function, and got it working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.